# Does the order in which providers are listed in a module matter in NestJs 10?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I recently upgraded my NestJs version from 8 to 10 and by changing the order in the `providers` list in a module, it affected my tests.

Here is my `document.module.ts` file:

```
// Imports

@Module({
  imports: [
    FirestoreModule.forFeature(['documents']),
    FirestoreModule.forFeature(['blanks']),
    MetricsModule.forFeature({
      documents: { prefix: 'documents.'}
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    DocumentService,
    DocumentProducerPdfLib,
    DocumentProducerSvgPdf,
    DocumentProducerOdtPdf,
    DocumentProducerJsonXml,
    DocumentProducerFodgPdf
  ],
  exports: [DocumentService]
})
export class DocumentModule { }
```

Regarding the providers' files in this list, they are all like the following example:

```
import { Injectable } from ‘@nestjs/common’;
import { Bucket } from ‘@google-cloud/storage’;

@Injectable()
export class DocumentProducerSvgPdf {
    constructor(
        @Inject('Bucket-bucket') private readonly bucket: Bucket)
    )
    // Other methods
}
```

When working with NestJs v8 my tests pass.
But when switching to NestJs v10, this happened:

- In `DocumentService`, the injection worked as expected. The variable `bucket` was defined.
- Variable `bucket` was **undefined** in all the other files. It was not being correctly injected.

It only worked when I moved `DocumentService` to the end of the providers list, like this:

```
// document.module.ts
// This code works for me in NestJs v10

@Module({
  imports: [
    FirestoreModule.forFeature(['documents']),
    FirestoreModule.forFeature(['blanks']),
    MetricsModule.forFeature({
      documents: { prefix: 'documents.'}
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    DocumentProducerPdfLib,
    DocumentProducerSvgPdf,
    DocumentProducerOdtPdf,
    DocumentProducerJsonXml,
    DocumentProducerFodgPdf,
    DocumentService // Moved here
  ],
  exports: [DocumentService]
})
export class DocumentModule { }
```

In summary, the way this code works is: DocumentService is first called and then directs to the right producer (DocumentProducerPdfLib, DocumentProducerSvgPdf, etc...).

**My questions are:** Does the providers list order matter? If it does, what has changed in the NestJs logic from 8 to 10, since the tests were passing in version 8?

I also read the NestJs migration docs and didn't find any relevant information on this matter.

Comment: It generally _shouldn't_ affect anything. The only reason I could think it might is if there's a circular dependency that you aren't currently showing

Comment: I used madge lib to detect circular dependencies but it didn't find any

Comment: Interesting. Can you share access to this? This shouldn't matter here